# No old revisions CPU use hight Sync Gateway Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

we have web application and mobile application using shadow bucket

I use Couchbase Sync Gateway 1.3.1
Couchbase Server 4.5.1
Couchbase lite 1.3.1

Problem:

in my log of sync Gateway there are too many lines of
CRUD+: No old revision "ID-DOCUMENT" / "rev"

since this log message appear the use of my cpu is more hight

i think its because i resolved conflicts in side mobile app but when i did the process i followed the documentation of couchbase

any idea about the problem ??

Comment: You mean you resolved the conflict by updating through Couchbase Server?  Which bucket did you use?

Comment: i resolved conflict in mobile app (IOS device)
The mobile app use shadow bucket

Comment: Shadow buckets are somewhat fragile.  It's no longer recommended to use this way.  It's hard to know the problem from the information you've given. 
 Better to post your question on the Couchbase Forums, since it may take some questions back and forth to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you solved or still opened this issue?

Comment: yes i update the version of couchbase and resolved the problem